# Traversing DOM in Javascript (nodeType)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I started exploring how to manipulate DOM with Javascript.
I started from the very basic but I got immediately stuck.

So from W3 I found that there are 3 types of nodes in HTML:

1. element
2. attribute
3. text

Taking this snippet as example `<p id="myId">My  paragraph</p>` I would say:

1. `<p>`
2. id
3. My paragraph

But when I apply this concept in code, it doesn't work.
Here my example:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>    
    <script>

        var htmlElement = document.documentElement;
        var headElement = htmlElement.firstChild
        var bodyElement = headElement.nextSibling;

        alert (bodyElement.nodeType);

    </script>
</body>
```

As you can imagine from my variable name, I would expect to have "1" as result of my alert (it would be the element 'body'), instead I receive a "3" which is a text. But I don't have any text in my "head" element.

How can I explain this?

Comment: `\n` is a character node

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> is a node also

Comment: @Ludo, yes but it isn't part of `document.documentElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript cares for the new line (\n) too so when you use nextSibling it get also get new line character.

So, using the following code:

```
headElement.nextSibling
```

will results `\n` now to get body element you need to use nextSibling again:

```
headElement.nextSibling.nextSibling
```

Alternatively, you may use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) by which you just get next sibling of type `element`:

```
headElement.nextElementSibling
```